# Set class on clicked navigation element

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Am using ASP.NET MVC to build a page. Now i have run into problems.

The following code is taken from my navigation list

```
        <li class="current start">
            <a href="/home">
                <i class="icon-home"></i>
                <span class="title">Dashboard</span>
                <span class="current"></span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="has-sub">
            <a href="javascript:;">
                <i class="icon-bookmark-empty"></i>
                <span class="title">Leads</span>
                <span class="arrow"></span>
                <span class=""></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="sub">
                <li><a href="/lead?status=1">Inkorg</a></li>
                <li><a href="/lead?status=2">Utskick</a></li>
                <li><a href="/lead?status=3">Akriverade</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
```

As you se it could be two levels of this navigation list.
I need to set class current on the clicked item and remember it after post. And in the second example i need to set class current both on the sub and top level of the li elements. Can i use cookie to remember this? Or what is the best way to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried anything? like ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would recommend using MVC routes to get the URL, rather than hard-coding it in the HTML, i.e.:

```
@Url.Action("Lead", new { status = 1 })
```

Or

```
@Url.RouteUrl("MyLeadRoute", new { status = 1 })
```

The second version allows you to use the named route instead of Action/Controller combo.

Then you would typically follow a pattern like:

```
@{ url = Url.Action("Lead", new { status = 1 }); }
<li@((Request.RawUrl == url) ? " class='current'" : "")><a href="@url">Some Link</a></li>
```

Note: you would need to define `@{ string url; }` earlier in your code.

Rinse and repeat for all your links.